# FragmentActivity detects the fragment that has the focus

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus, android-viewpager

I have an activity with a ViewPager that contains three fragments

```
    public class Hello extends extends FragmentActivity
...
adapterViewPager.addFragment(new FRG_one());
adapterViewPager.addFragment(new FRG_two());
adapterViewPager.addFragment(new FRG_three());
adapterViewPager.addFragment(new FRG_four());
...
```

Within the activity, I have a button that when pressed I want to do one action or another, depending on the fragment that is being displayed on the screen

I found ways to detect if a fragment is visible, but do not serve me.

What I need is that the activity that contains the viewpager (extends FragmentActivity) detects fragment has focus

I appreciate the help

regards :)

Comment: You mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-viewpager ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29) to listen for page changes. Your listener can store the current page position in its [`onPageSelected(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected%28int%29) callback, then just vary your button action based on that.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an [onPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html)? This will fire a callback when the view pager displays a new page or fragment. You can use the supplied index to determine which fragment is currently in focus.

Answer (score 0):

Create a loop that goes through all your fragments and check the `.isVisible()` method if it returns true, if it returns true then `break;`, else keep going.